# Some puzzles about python mutability and immutablity

Tags: python, computer-science, immutability, mutable

I'm confused about the following 3 codes.

1.The first one is intuitive for me util I saw (B):

(A)

```
def change (mylist):
    mylist[0] = 33
    mylist[1] = 44
    mylist[2] = 55
    print("inside the function",mylist)

alist = [10,20,30]
change(alist)
print("outside the function",alist)
```

the output is:

inside the function [33, 44, 55]

outside the function [33, 44, 55]

2.As I saw the (B), I have trouble telling the difference of (A) and (B).

(B)

```
def change2 (mylist):
    mylist = [33,44,55]
    print("inside the funcion",mylist)

blist = [10,20,30]
change2(blist)
print("outside the funcion",blist)
```

the output is:

inside the function [33, 44, 55]

outside the function [10, 20, 30]

3.then, the third one is (C), and I  can't figure out why "a" can't be changed to 5.

(C)

```
def change3(mylist,number):
    mylist[0] = 33
    mylist[1] = 44
    mylist[2] = 55
    number = 5
    print("inside the function",mylist,number)

clist = [10,20,30]
a = 50
change3(clist,a)
print("outside the function",clist,a)
```

the output is:

inside the function [33, 44, 55] 5

outside the function [33, 44, 55] 50

I know they might be have something with mutable or immutable concept, but I don't know the clear concept behind the three codes. Could someone explain them? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the variable you modify inside the function for it to reflect in the outer values

Eg :

```
def change3(mylist,number):
    mylist[0] = 33
    mylist[1] = 44
    mylist[2] = 55
    number = 5

    return mylist, number

clist = [10, 20, 30]
a = 50
output = change3(clist, a)
print("outside the function", output)
```

Same for the all the cases you have mentioned.Since you have not returned,nothing is changing in the print which is outside the function and youre getting the unmodified values.

Comment: no actually I don't want to change it, I just want to know the concept behind those codes